# How much temperature control does an emergency food cache need?

Tags: storage-lifetime

I just bought a massive amount of wholesale food to prepare for a winter storm this coming weekend. Since I will not use all of it, and want to keep it around for future emergencies, I'm curious about some of the items I have.

None of the items I bought were refrigerated but I am wondering how some of them would fair in the northwestern US with its cold winters and warm summers, namely jam, [these milk boxes](https://www.boxed.com/product/4217/horizon-organic-lowfat-milk-18-x-8-oz.-plain?pf=3&gid=4217&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=shopping-supplier-top&utm_purpose=all&utm_experiment=none&utm_ad_id=328299188868&utm_term=&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI9Zyf7uOo4AIVA73sCh3t4Qu-EAQYASABEgInt_D_BwE), canned tuna, soups, etc.

I wanted to keep these large bins of food in my outdoor shed but ***will the food spoil if it 1) freezes and thaws during the cold months or 2) gets up into the 70's and 80's during summer?***

I can keep reminders for any expiration dates, but for the packages that say "no need to refrigerated until opened", I'm concerned it will go to waste.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: you need to keep those goods above freezing, below 85F, and in a low-humidity environment.

Long Answer:

Freezing: Canned goods, jars, and tetrapaks that are frozen [can leak, split, or even explode](https://www.fsis.usda.gov/wps/portal/fsis/topics/food-safety-education/get-answers/food-safety-fact-sheets/safe-food-handling/freezing-and-food-safety/CT_Index/!ut/p/a1/jZDbCsIwDIafxQcoyZyKXkpB7HQb4qn2RorrtsLsZCuent6qNyqekpsk__eTEBDAQRi515m0ujSyuPais8YJdrwexSDueQNk0WISjyjF7rTtgNUXIPL_9H-IPv7yB38saFYhDTMQO2lzok1aAs-UJdLUB1XVwNOyTEgtU2VPJJUbS-pcKeuE64zc1FyapNAmc3Cl1NlVzp6QBydwOlszk6gjLEE8X4WeSxb509YwiHyMW6_Am7fdgc9_2W3n_DzuD1GzxgW5m4RF/#17), and are often unsafe to eat after thawing.

Heat: canned goods [safe and nutritious lifetime decreases at temperatures above 85F](https://extension.umn.edu/preserving-and-preparing/storing-canned-food), and US regulations allow them to fail preservation outright at 100F (which means some).  TetraPak also [recommends against](http://www.shieldhealthcare.com/community/nutrition/2017/10/30/storing-using-tetra-pack-formula-containers/) exposing those milk cartons to temperatures above 100F for more than 24 hours.

Moisture: cans and jar lids can and do rust, and [if the rust penetrates into the interior can cause seal failure](https://extension.umn.edu/preserving-and-preparing/storing-canned-food).  While TetraPak provides no information about failure modes, they also recommend storing cartons in a dry environment.

So, if you want those supplies to be wholesome and nutritious until their printed expiration dates, store them between 33F and 85F in a dry place.  In Florida, that might be a challenge, but in the NW USA, you can solve that by putting them in a well-lined, well-drained cellar.